# How to apply a function if an expression evaluates to true

Tags: operators

I'm trying to define a simple function that will accept a symbol and an expression, set the symbol equal to the expression, and then print out info about the equation. Like so:

```
ClearAll[showValue];
Attributes[showValue] = {HoldAll};
Options[showValue] = {"N" -> False, "S" -> False};
showValue[sym_, value_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{},
   sym = value;
   Print[
    HoldForm[sym], " = ",
    If[OptionValue["S"], ScientificForm] If[OptionValue["N"], 
      N] value
    ]
   ];
```

as you can see, I want to have some options that i can use to change the format of the output. What I would like is so that if the If evaluates to true, that it will return the function header in such a way as to apply the function to the arguments that are to the if statements' right. If effect, if the options given are:

```
showValue[k, 
  UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"], ("Electronvolts")/(
   "Kelvins")], "N" -> True, "S" -> True];
```

then the result will be:

```
k = ScientificForm@N@k = 8.61733*10^(-5)eV/K
```

The purpose of this is so I can avoid an extremely large and burdensome branching tree, once I put in more options. My understanding of Mathematica leads me to believe that something like this is possible because we have operator behavior and functions that can return operators, I just don't know what the syntax for that is suppose to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know if this is the best or most efficient way to perform this task, but here is the code I came up with:

```
ClearAll[Pass];
Pass[x_] := x;
ClearAll[showValue];
Attributes[showValue] = {HoldAll};
Options[showValue] = {"N" -> False, "S" -> False};
showValue[sym_, value_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{},
   sym = value;
   Print[
    HoldForm[sym], " = ",
    Composition[If[OptionValue["S"], ScientificForm, Pass], 
      If[OptionValue["N"], N, Pass]][value]
    ]
   ];
```

I simply use a Pass function that just returns the argument, then use Composition to form the proper chain of functions. Again, I feel as though I am missing an easier path, so if anyone knows better, please let me know.